# What Query should I make to prefetch my data from first model to get filled when my form for second model opens

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

## models.py

```
class Appname(models.Model):
      name=models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False,null=False,help_text='Add your new App')

      def __str__(self):
           return self.name

      def get_absolute_url(self):
           return reverse("dashapp:view")

class Adspace(models.Model):
      name=models.ForeignKey(Appname,related_name='adspaces', null=True, default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      ad_space=models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False,null=False) 

      def __str__(self):
          return self.ad_space

      def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse("dashapp:view")
```

## Query to make

I create a form using CreateView for both the models. For First model i save the appname and then I create a listview of app names Using ListView and display them. When i click on one of the app from the displayed list it takes me to the next form which is for the next model `Adspace` . Now I want as my form opens  for second model the name section gets autofill with the name of the app with which i clicked to reach on that form.What Query should i make to make it possible.Please Explain it with your answer.

Comment: Show us the code for your view and form for creating `Adspace`. Are you using a `ModelForm`?

Comment: No , I'm using CreateView for making Form. And to display App names I'm using generic ListView .

Comment: So When I click on any of the app names I go the Next form which is also made by using CreateView. In that Section I want the name section of the second model gets autofill by the app name which we clicked to reach to this form.

Comment: How do you pass the app name that was clicked on to the `CreateView`? Is it in the URL?

Comment: No ,that is what i want to know,I'm a beginner. So I'm not passing anything when the Appname is being clicked as I dont know things like that can be done or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a generic `CreateView`, you can override the `get_initial()` method to set initial values for the object that's being created:

```
def get_initial(self):
    # assuming the Appname id is passed in the view's kwargs as "app_id"
    try:
        app = Appname.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['app_id'])
        return super().get_initial().update({'name': app})
    except Appname.DoesNotExist:
        return super().get_initial()
```

Comment: How can I pass app_id in views kwargs .??

Comment: Well, you'll need to create a url path that has the `app_id` as one of the parameters, so it'll be available to your view. Read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/). This is basic Django, please take some time to learn it properly (do the entire tutorial step by step).

Comment: Ohkie Sir,Let me go through this, If i get stuck somewhere I'll ping you here.

Comment: Ask a new question then, the answer to this question is to override `get_initial()`

Comment: I used get_initial() method in my View  and I'm getting the appname but it is not able to autofill appname in the next form. But I'm getting the appnames as scrollbox their not as autofill

Comment: What do you mean “auto fill”? The get_initial just sets the initial value for the field (Pre-selects the value), it doesn’t remove the ability for the user to then change the value. So a <select> box is still expected.

Comment: By autofill what i meant is when i click on a `App` and page for my next form opens up . The CLICKED app name should be  filled in my name section of the 2nd model form

Comment: well, if you implement the `get_initial()` as shown in your second view (the CreateView that generates the 2nd form) it should pre-select the value.

Comment: No but it doesn't preselects the value . What I'm getting is list of app names in a scroll .

Comment: With nothing selected in that list? That's not possible. And you're not customising the form? Then show us your template (the part where you display the selector for the `App`). Also maybe add some print statements in `get_initial()` to make sure you return the first option, not the second one.

Comment: Yeah, I did the print part and it's printing the same app as clicked but when form is opened I get list of apps name in a scroll box with nothing selected.  And no I'm not customising the form

Comment: What's your template code for rendering the select widget?

Comment: Can I connect to you in some way that I can show you my entire problem in my project . If it's not a problem for you??